# List taxonomies with thumbnails

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I've added an extra field to a taxonomy called "albums" via this function:

```
add_action( 'albums_edit_form_fields', 'albums_taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 2 );
function save_taxonomy_custom_meta( $term_id ) {
if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {
    $t_id = $term_id;
    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
    $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['term_meta'] );
    foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ) {
        if ( isset ( $_POST['term_meta'][$key] ) ) {
            $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
        }
    }
    // Save the option array.
    update_option( "taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta );
}
}
```

The metadata is saving fine and now I'd like to list or query my taxonomies in a page by displaying next to the taxonomy's name the value of the metadata attached to every taxonomy (in this case, the image). Anybody knows how to do it ?

Comment: Just for the sake of testing, can you post the full code?

Comment: @job78 Any progress on this question?

Answer (score 1):

### How to get the data back

When you look at your code, then you got `get_option( "taxonomy_{$t_id}" )` in it, which actually calls the value from the DB options table. So you should simply replace the `$t_id` with your actual term id.

The term ID can be retrieved via

- `get_query_var( 'tag_id' )` for Tags on tag archive pages
- `get_query_var( 'cat' )` for Categories on cat archive pages
- `get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) )->term_id` for custom taxonomy and post format pages.

### Why it is NOT recommended to do this!

You're saving **one additional entry** in your DB options table **per tag/term/category/taxon**.

This means with a growing number of taxonomy terms, tags or categories, you're quickly polluting your table with stuff that doesn't belong there. Its also **not recommended** to prefix custom stuff with a generic name like `taxonomy_`. Try to find this again, when you don't need it anymore. There's also a high risk, that you may catch stuff that doesn't belong to your custom "solution". **Always!** use a proper prefix like `wpse38656_` for DB entries.